Unable to get the proper data of La Liga Points Table from the FC Barcelona website using BS4
Im trying to extract the points table data from the https://www.fcbarcelona.com/en/football/first-team/standings website. I want to extract the data of the current table (24-25) but it is extracting the previous years (23-24) table data
Code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.fcbarcelona.com/en/football/first-team/standings'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

team_names_tag = soup.find_all("span", class_="team-row__name--short")
team_names=[]
               
for team_name in team_names_tag:
   team_names.append(team_name.text.replace("\n", "").strip())

print(team_names)


points_tag = soup.find_all("td", class_="table-stat-row table-stat-row--points")
points=[]
               
for point in points_tag:
   points.append(point.text.replace("\n", "").strip())

print(points)

Output:
['R. Madrid', 'FC Barcelona', 'Girona', 'Atlético', 'Athletic Club', 'Real Sociedad', 'Betis', 'Villarreal', 'Valencia', 'Alavés', 'Osasuna', 'Getafe', 'Celta de Vigo', 'Sevilla', 'Mallorca', 'UD Las Palmas', 'Rayo', 'Cádiz', 'Almería', 'Granada']
['95', '85', '81', '76', '68', '60', '57', '53', '49', '46', '45', '43', '41', '41', '40', '40', '38', '33', '21', '21']


As stated in other solution, use the api to access that data. You'll then need to parse the json to get what ever info you want. The nice part about this is you'll get all the data available. Here's how you'd code that.
Code:
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api-fcb.pulselive.com/football//standings'
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
    'compSeasons': '724',
    'detail': '2',
    'altIds': 'true'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData,
                       record_path=['tables', 'entries'])


The site initially sends only results for the previous season. By switching the season in the browser with "developer tools" on, in the Network tab, you can see that it then downloads other seasons as needed, and also that it automatically loads the 24/25 season when you open the site in the browser, but as a separate javascript request (after the main html is already loaded).
These additional requests are (at the moment) of the form https://api-fcb.pulselive.com/football//standings?compSeasons=724&detail=2&altIds=true. They also happen to return JSON, rather than HTML,  which should be much simpler to parse (hopefully just call response.json()).
